# changes I make in @vue/cli app are not applied with local server

Tags: vuejs2

working with @vue/cli 4.0.5 in dev mode 
I run server locally and very often I see changes I make in my  PhpStorm 2019.2.3  are not applied to my running local server

I see output in the console :

```
$ npm run serve

> ctasks@0.1.0 serve /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/VApps/vtasks
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 8350ms                                                                                                                                                                                             6:18:04 PM


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: unavailable

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

But to see my changes in Phpstorm applied I need to close console with local server...
Just thought is it safe to close console with running server ?

What is the reason and how it can be treated ?

```
uname -a

    Linux athoe 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ctasks",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vee-validate": "^3.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-focus": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-js-modal": "^1.3.31",
    "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-select": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "vue2-filters": "^0.8.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you enable the auto save on window change ?

Comment: Do you mean PhpStorm option? Please clerify.
Also I seems to me this problem started after I begin working with Nuxt app with default localhost:3000 port.

I mean I work  in one Kubuntu session , switching from one app to other in console and closing 
console with running localhost and running commands 

npm run serve / npm run dev

Can it be the issue and how it can be detected / salved ?

Comment: Has anybody such problems ? That becomes issue for me…


\

Comment: I made some additive checks :
1) Editing vue files of the project in defautl kate editor
2) I opened the project in Visual Studio Code
I see that my changes are not applied, until I close console and run
npm run serve

again

So I suppose that it is not PhpStorm options issue?